# how to use sequellize.fn with SQL TIMESTAMPDIFF function having more than 1 args

Tags: sequelize.js

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT mbr_id
FROM `tbl_logs` 
WHERE mbr_id = 187 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, log_datetime, NOW()) < 60
ORDER BY `log_datetime` DESC
```

How do I sequelize this?

My confusion lies on the SQL functions especially those with more than 1 arguments in them.  The samples [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn) just provide a function that accepts one argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you provided the signature is

```
public static fn(fn: string, args: any): fn
```

`args: any` means that you can specify/pass more than one argument (parameter) seperated by commas. In your case you might think that the signature is like this

```
public static fn(fn: string, arg1, arg2, arg3): fn
```

So you should use it like this:

```
sequelize.fn('timestampdiff', sequelize.literal('minute'), sequelize.col('log_datetime'), sequelize.fn('now'))
```